# Drop multiple columns using subquery within alter table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery, alter-table

I need to drop all but few columns from a table while I don't know number and names of these columns in advance. I want to get column names from sys.columns and then drop all columns except few. I need something like this:

```
alter table Table
drop column (
            select a.name as ColumnName 
            from sys.all_columns a
            INNER JOIN sys.tables b
            on a.object_id = b.object_id
            where b.name = 'Table'
            where a.name NOT IN (
                                     RowID, 
                                     RemoteUserId, 
                                     Email, 
                                     FirstName, 
                                 )
            )
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible without creating the alter table ddl statement dynamically.

Comment: You can drop only one column at time. If there are many columns and you do not want to write the statements alone, you can use dynamic SQL to build them.

Comment: You can create a temp table, pump all data to it, drop the table and rename the temp to match the dropped one. Or you can just make a query to create the many drop columns statements

Comment: Are you sure you're doing things the correct way? Maybe just running select 'alter table xxx drop column ' + name from sys.columns ... and then just run the statements manually would be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You need to Create a `Function` to Split the `Comma Separated Strings` to `Rows`

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FnSplit]
(
@List nvarchar(2000),
@SplitOn nvarchar(5)
)  
RETURNS @RtnValue table 
(

Id int identity(1,1),
Value nvarchar(100)
) 
AS  
BEGIN
While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)>0)
Begin 
Insert Into @RtnValue (value)
Select
Value = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@List,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)-1))) 
Set @List = Substring(@List,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)+len(@SplitOn),len(@List))
End 

Insert Into @RtnValue (Value)
Select Value = ltrim(rtrim(@List))
Return
END
GO
```

Then Create Below `Stored Procedure`

```
 Create Procedure DropColumnExceptGivn
 @table  varchar(50),
 @Column Varchar(max)
 AS
 BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
      declare @variables AS TABLE (cols varchar(max))
      declare @sql varchar(max) = ''
      declare @sql1 varchar(max) = ''
      declare @cols nvarchar(max) =''


  set @sql1 = 'SELECT Stuff((select '',''+ Column_name '+'from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where 
            table_name = ' +''''+@table+''''+
            ' and column_name not in (SELECT Value FROM dbo.FnSplit('+''''+@column+''''+','','')) 
            for xml path('''')),1,1,'''')'
  print @sql1

  insert into @variables
  exec (@sql1)  
  select @cols = cols  from @variables 
  select @cols 

  set @sql= 'alter table '+ @table + ' drop column ' + @cols 

  print @sql 

  exec (@sql)
  end

  go
```

--Creating a Sample Table

```
Create table pets1 (petid int, PetTypeID int, PetName Varchar(20),OwnerId int)
go
```

Then Execute the below `Stored Procedure.`
                                                                                             The Parameters are :                                                                          1. Table Name 2. The Columns need to be Left (Comma Seperated values)

```
exec DropColumnExceptGivn 'pets1','PetID, PetTypeID'

go
select *from pets1
```

Hope This will helps

Comment: No, I only know which are columns need to be left. The table is continuously updated and new columns are added. Every once in a while I need to drop all columns that were added.